# Xcode - SKSceneKit Level Editor - How do you connect to variables in .h

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit

In Xcode how do you connect your items in the level editor to the variables in the .h file? I Can't seem to find documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about SpriteKit (the 2D game engine, with an Xcode editor for `SKScene` objects archived as `.sks` files) or SceneKit (the 3D game engine, with an editor for assets imported from `.dae` or `.abc` files)?

In either case, you don't hook up objects to code directly like you do in Interface Builder (storyboards or `xib`/`nib` files). (Though that would be an awesome [feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com)!) Instead, you set names (identifiers) for the entities in the scene editor; then, in code, you can look up entities by their names.

In SpriteKit, use the [childNodeWithName:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName%3a) method on an `SKScene` object to find a named node. See [Searching the Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW17) for advanced searching options (such as recursively searching for descendant nodes).

In Scene Kit, use the  method on an `SCNScene` object's [`rootNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNScene_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNScene/rootNode) to find a named node.

Comment: I was hoping that you could hook up the SKObjects visually and not have to do it via ChildNodeWithName.  It seemed obvious to me that this would work just like Interface Builder.  So would you suggest that in the initWithSize procedure I get all the Nodes in the view or just get the nodes as I need them?  Any sample code out there?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: @fawsha1 So if your object is named 'bouncingBall', then in your code (Swift), you could do: `let ball = childNodeWithName("ball");`